# emacs lisp skip-syntax-forward help

Tags: syntax, emacs, lisp

I am trying to implement function which moves to the next blank/whitespace character.
I have read manual, and it seems I can use skip-syntax functions. However, I cannot figure out how to use them correctly.
Here is what I have:

```
(skip-syntax-forward " ")
```

However, this does not seem to work. If I use "^ " it works, but if point is one blank character already, points does not move forward.

What is the correct usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(when (= 0 (skip-syntax-forward "^ ")) 
  (skip-syntax-forward " ") 
  (skip-syntax-forward "^ "))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(skip-syntax-forward "^-")
```

Comment: hi. Can you explain significance of "^" please? is it regular expression or something else?

Comment: from the help for skip-syntax-forward: "If syntax starts with ^, skip characters whose syntax is NOT in syntax."